# how to close/finish System AppInfo Screen from my app

Tags: android

how to close/finish System AppInfo Screen from my application. actually System AppInfo Screen open directly from my application by below code

```
 public static void showInstalledAppDetails(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    final int apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (apiLevel >= 9) { // above 2.3
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.putExtra("frommyapp", true);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts(SCHEME, packageName, null);
        intent.setData(uri);
    } else { // below 2.3
        final String appPkgName = (apiLevel == 8 ? APP_PKG_NAME_22
                : APP_PKG_NAME_21);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.putExtra("frommyapp", true);
        intent.setClassName(APP_DETAILS_PACKAGE_NAME,
                APP_DETAILS_CLASS_NAME);
        intent.putExtra(appPkgName, packageName);
    }
    intent.putExtra("extraData", "somedata");
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

after open system appinfo screen then i want to close/finish system appinfo screen when click "Force Stop" button without back button press

so please help me to solve this type of issues.

Comment: put the full class code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue myself..

use `finishActivity(requestcode);

when you start activity  by

```
startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode);
```

use this requestcode at the time of finishactivity by

```
finishActivity(requestcode);
```